# AWS cost one vs many lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda

I am currently developing an API management platform where it is possible to move every endpoint action to a serverless function (lambda).

My question is: It is cheaper to use a single lambda function which then invokes the complete app and the app makes internally the routing or it is better to use the AWS routing and create a lambda for each endpoint, in my case this could be (100+) lambda instances.

From a technical perspective I think it is better to have multiple lambda functions since then we can also scale each function independently but I am not sure how it looks on the costs side. So please let me know if you have any experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/lambda-tools/pricing-calculator.html

The most important thing to keep in mind, is run short time functions at lambda, slow executions can increase your budget! But many lambda fast invokes no!

You need to know your executions time! To maintain a very large set of lambda functions i recommend to you:
https://www.serverless.com/